# Java: Unable to access the remote MySQL database using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, networking, jdbc, cpanel

I am trying to access the MySQL database, which is installed in my Web server, using my Java code. My Java application is a Swing application, running in my PC. Below is my Java code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;


public class TestDatabase {

    private Connection con;

    private void connect()
    {
        try
        {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://72.0.0.0:3306/aceko_test","aceko_me","rtf7890");

             System.out.println("Connection Established");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new TestDatabase().connect();
    }

}
```

I am getting the below error.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1129)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:358)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2320)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at TestDatabase.connect(TestDatabase.java:31)
    at TestDatabase.main(TestDatabase.java:43)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:308)
    ... 16 more
```

I have done my knowledge best in `CPanel` of my web server to assign the remote access. As you can see in below image, I have provided the "Any Access"

[image]

As you can see in the below image, I have created the database, user, and assigned the user to the database.

[image]

Please note the IP I have mentioned in my code is fake, only for the use of SO.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but the java code is running as a desktop app?

Comment: @Jessai: Yes, it is a swing application.

Comment: I remember once I tried to do the same in PHP. The reason you can't connect with your code is because you need a secure and static IP. Feel free to correct If I am wrong :D

Comment: Looks like network connection is blocked, firewall maybe?. Check that you can actually access the IP and port of your MySQL database from the machine you are running your code on. telnet useful for that ' telnet <IP> <port>'

Comment: @dethorpe: Tried telnet, it says `connection failed`. I even paused the Kasperky Internet security.

Comment: @Sniper your server's firewall is probably blocking your connection

Answer (score 1):

Hunting in Google I found [this article](http://www.haciendoti.com/remote-access-mysql-from-any-ip/) that shows how to connect a DBMS, but is on spanish. Anyway I try to traslate the article:

1.- Modify /etc/mysql/my.cnf file
You have to comment the **skip-external-locking** and **bind-address** entries

```
    [mysqld]
    #
    # * Basic Settings
    #
    user            = mysql
    pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    port            = 3306
    basedir         = /usr
    datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
    tmpdir          = /tmp
    lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
    #skip-external-locking
    #
    # Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
    # localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
    #bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

2.- Give permissions to the user with the following commands

```
haciendoti@haciendoti:~$ sudo mysql -u root -ppasswd

mysql > GRANT ALL ON *.* TO haciendoti@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';
```

3.- Add exception to firewall (I don't know if you can do this in your server)

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Best regards.

Comment: `'%'` will allow connections from any ip address, and port `3306` is the default port. This in combination is asking for bots et al to try brute forcing. I'd recommend either changing to a non-standard port (not fool proof but will get past most dumb bots) and/or limiting the user account to only the IP address necessary it will connect from (ie your office's public static ip address).